# How to work with old .jar files when porting a project to AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was able to create a new AndroidStudio project and port my old code to it.

But now I get some compilation errors about some libraries Like Flurry not being recognized.

See this screenshot where the reference to Flurry is red:

[image]

And this is how my old .jars used to be:

[image]

What is the way that I need to port the jars? Should that be handled through Gradle now? How should I do it? Now my Gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "problemio.com.problemionew"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Should I add lines like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:acra-4.2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:android-support-v4'
compile 'com.android.support:FlurryAgent'
compile 'com.android.support:gcm-server'
compile 'com.android.support:gcm'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add jars to your project, move your jars to the `libs` folder and in your grade file, do something like:

```
compile files 'your.jar.file.name.here.jar'
```

for each jar you want to import.

That should do the trick.

The folders would look like:

[image: folder heirarchy]

and then the dependencies block would look something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

    compile files('libs/android_antlib_4-12-0.jar')
}
```

Comment: thank you, but when UdemyStudio made the new file it didn't make a libs folder :) Where should I put these jars now?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you can create your libs folder just in case Android Studio imported it and didn't make a libs folder for you (just like in Eclipse) then move your jars there.

Comment: Thank you - I am looking at it and thinking...it is probably better practice to let Gradle take care of this for me instead of porting the jars, right?

Comment: And I don't already have a libs folder...where should I make the libs folder in  my file system if I want to copy the jars?

Comment: If your jars would have a gradle "equivalent/link" then yes, and most jars would have a grade equivalent by now. If you want to make your own libs folder, it should be at the same level as the src folder.

Comment: I moved it there but it still doesn't recognize the Flurry library and the R class that is used like setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using those jars, locate them in the directory indicated by the line

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This compiles any `jar` files located in the `libs` folder, where the `libs` folder is directly inside your `app` folder:

[image: A screenshot showing the location of the libs folder relative to the app folder]

If you want to swap to dependency versions stored in a remote maven repository (e.g. jCenter or Maven Central), then you can instead use the separate `compile` statements you list at the end of your question and let Gradle do the hard work. You will need to specify some version information for *each* dependency, however; see `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` for the correct format for a fully-specified dependency version.

Comment: thank you - I am ok with not porting the jars but letting gradle handle it. Does it actually download those jars? How does it work?

Comment: Good question. There's enough substance here for a whole new SO question if you want! The short answer is: yes, Gradle downloads and caches those jars for you in a centralized location (normally `~/.gradle`). See [section 52.9](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) of the user guide for the gory details.